# How can I use a typed HttpClient in the .NET Framework 4.8?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.8

I can find examples for ASP.NET and .NET Core everywhere, but I can't find detailed examples for the .NET Framework. I want to get around common errors with DNS and creating a socket for each request. This is a very confusing topic for me, there is different information on this everywhere. As I understand, HttpClient in ".Net Framework 4.5 and +" has the following dependency: HttpClient -> HttpClientHandler -> HttpWebRequest, which means I can use ServicePointManager and ServicePoint. And do I need to configure SocketHttpHandler to achieve my goals, or can I use IHttpFactoryHandler instead of typed clients, or is all this only available on .NET Core/ASP.NET, or will ServicePointManager and ServicePoint be enough to achieve my goals?
Recall that I want to combat the problem of multiple socket creation and the need to update DNS when the IP address of the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) service suddenly changes.

Am I using typed clients in .Net Framework 4.8 Windows Forms correctly? What is missing in my code?

```
public class DocumentInfoResponse
{
    public int status { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyApiServiceClient
{
    Task<DocumentInfoResponse> GetDocumentStatusAsync(string docId);
}

public sealed class MyApiServiceClient : IMyApiServiceClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    
    private MyApiServiceClient() { }
    
    public MyApiServiceClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<DocumentInfoResponse> GetDocumentStatusAsync(string docId)
    {
        var url = $"/api/v3/document/id&docId={docId}";
        AddHeaders();
        _httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocumentInfoResponse>(json);
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("error");
    }

    private void AddHeaders()
    {
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }
}

public sealed class MyApiServiceControl
{
    private readonly IMyApiServiceClient _client;
    
    private MyApiServiceControl() { }
    
    public MyApiServiceControl(IMyApiServiceClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }
    
    public async Task<DocumentInfoResponse> GetDocumentStatusAsync(string docId)
    {
        return await _client.GetDocumentStatusAsync(docId);
    }
}

public static class ServiceHandler
{
    private static readonly ServiceCollection _services = new ServiceCollection();
    public static ServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }

    public static void InitializeTypedClients()
    {
        _services.AddHttpClient<IMyApiServiceClient, MyApiServiceClient>((client, serviceProvider) =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://www.example.com");
            return new MyApiServiceClient(client);
        });
        ServiceProvider = _services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        //InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceHandler.InitializeTypedClients();

        var client = ServiceHandler.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyApiServiceClient>();
        var result = await new MyApiServiceControl(client).GetDocumentStatusAsync("123-qwerty-456qaz");

        label.Text = result.status.ToString();

        // or

        var list = new List<DocumentInfoResponse>();
        var client2 = ServiceHandler.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyApiServiceClient>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var result2 = await new MyApiServiceControl(client2).GetDocumentStatusAsync(i.ToString());
            list.Add(result2);
        }
        // list processing ...
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand well your question.. but I had some problems with HttpClient with Winforms applications and I solved it changing the the HttpClient to static, like this:
        public static HttpClient client = new HttpClient()

Comment: @ThiagoAraújo I started out that way too, but when different queries required different wait times, I started changing the "Timeout" via an object property. The problem was that if this property was already set and then a query was executed, I could not set a new value in the Timeout property as an exception was generated.
I was advised to use typed clients, this means "1 object - 1 request" and now I can configure an object of type HttpClient as I need for different requests. Do you understand?

Comment: @ThiagoAraújo I.e. if I use a GET request - I may need to wait 2 seconds for a response to get a string of 36 characters.
And if I use POST and send a signed document with a data size of 0.5Mb, I may need to wait up to 120 seconds for a response, as the processing time of the document may take a significant amount of time. So for GET I need to wait up to 30 seconds and for POST 120 seconds.
This is an example of two requests. Do you understand the problem? the timeout problem + the dns problem + the sockets problem

Comment: Yeah, now I got your problem. I think you need use a HttpClientHandler. I will put it in the answer to show you better.

Comment: Sorry guy, It's not possible with HttpClientHandler. I suggest you creat two HttpClients for same server, one for each different timeout. Probably you won't have DNS problems with just two HttpClient's.

Comment: @ThiagoAraújo Thanks for the reply, but I have already migrated the project to .NET Core, using SocketsHttpHandler + CancellationToken and have no problems :))

Comment: Thanks to share. I use HttpClient a lot and good to know that!